# Adding the sum of best 5 of 7 cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, array-formulas

So I have tried to use sumproduct to pull data from cells. My issue is that I would prefer to pick 5 individual cells vs a bank of cells. 
I can make this formula below work, but it pulls "Place" cell values into the equation as well as "Points" value cells

**Image of cells and formula**

[image]

I would like to use the formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Large(C5,G5,K5,O5,S5,W5,AA5,{1,2,3,4,5))
```

to pull only from the 7 specific cells, but I get an error. as soon as I enter large, it only has the first 3 cells highlighted.

The error states that You've entered too many arguments for this function.

Comment: It seems the question has nothing to do with programming, so it is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: I would sum all seven items and then remove the two smallest using small() - which will have the same issues as large(), but also the same solutions...

Answer (score 1):

I am new to the Large formula as well, but it can only accept an array, not individual cells. You did specify individual cells which would lead to the next argument. 

Since the Large formula only excepts 2 arguments you have too many and it fails with an error.

 It is not a nice solution, but I guess the formula could work if you put your specific individual cells in neighbouring cells to create the array needed for the formula. (Or at least refer to them in some other cells to create the Array)
For the result you also would need 5 cells to enter the Sumproduct formula to display in each cell the 5 individual results.
Similar to:
=SUMPRODUCT(Large(A1:A7,1))
Where A1:A7 would be the newly created array where you reference:
in Cell A1 =C5
in Cell A2 = G5
in Cell A3 = K5
etc.

Comment: Thanks... I created another sheet that pulled information from the first. that allowed an array to be used and the formula to work.

Answer (score 0):

The [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/large-function-3af0af19-1190-42bb-bb8b-01672ec00a64) expects a single contiguous range as its first argument.

This array formula should circumvent that restriction.

```
=SUM(LARGE(IF(MOD(COLUMN(C:AA), 4)=3, C5:AA5), ROW($1:$5)))
```